# Applications of Strong Whitney Embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, embeddings

I am looking for applications of the strong Whitney's embedding theorem that have an advantage over weak theorems. That is, applications where it's important that the dimension of the Euclidian space be minimal.

Comment: The strong Whitney embedding theorem rarely provides a minimal dimension.  For example, 3-manifolds embed in $\mathbb R^5$.    By and large the weak theorem has more general applicability, as it's part of a relatively basic approximation theorem, and is a manifestation of transversality, or general position.  The strong theorem is part of a more subtle approximation theory.

Comment: Whenever a theorem in differential topology is proved by first applying Whitney's theorem, a bound on the dimension helps to get a better stable range. Sometimes, an abstract topological construction becomes geometrically easier if the dimension of the ambient space is smaller. Though I have no concrete example in mind, I believe there must be many constructions that work only because one has the strong Whitney theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the info!